# Java client/server issue sending objects over sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm creating a standard multi-client/server program in Java.  The server accepts connections and spawns a new thread to handle each one.  The client also spawns a thread to wait for messages from the server.  The client and server communicate by passing Message objects through ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStreams.

The initial handshake works fine.  When the client starts, it opens a socket connection to the server.  The server accepts the socket, sends a Message to the client that the connection was successful.  Then the client sends its username back, and both client and server start waiting for messages.

Then I send some text from my client which creates a chat message, and sends it successfully to the server.  The server receives this message, and attempts to send it out to all connected clients, which it does (there's only one).  The problem is that this message never gets back to the client.

```
// This is Message.send
public void send(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException{
        stream.writeObject(this);
}

// ClientThread.run
public void run(){
    try {
        out = client.getOutputStream();
        out.flush();
        ObjectInputStream in = client.getInputStream();

        Message msg = null;
        int len;
        byte[] bytes = null;
        int i = 0;

        // Continuously read new Messages from the server
        while(true){
            msg = (Message)in.readObject();

            processInput(msg);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Util.showError(e.getMessage(), "Connection Error");
    }

    System.out.println("Client exited");
}

// ServerThread.run
public void run() {
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

        Message msg = null;

        while(client.isConnected()){
            msg = (Message)in.readObject();
            processInput(msg);
        }

        in.close();
        client.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        server.addMessage(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, consider using SOAP or REST instead of slogging through this?

Comment: It's an exercise so I can practice with sockets at a lower level without using an existing protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any calls to `flush()`, without which the data may never make it from point a to point b.

I'd recommend using the ObjectOutputStream atop a ByteArrayOutputStream, and pushing the resulting byte array across the wire, and then reversing the process on the other end.

Comment: I added a flush() after the writeObject call in send(), and one after instantiating each of the ObjectOutputStreams.  No luck though.